# Passing from a summation to an integral in Klenke's Probability Theory book

Tags: probability, measure-theory

I'm using the 2nd edition of Klenke's Probability Theory.

Let $f:\Omega\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be measurable and $\geq 0$ a.e. on some measure space $(\Omega,\mu)$ and define $g(t):= \mu\{f\geq t\}$, assumed to be finite for all $t> 0$. For $\epsilon > 0$, $k\in\mathbb{N}$, let $g^{\epsilon}:= \min\{g, g(\epsilon)\}$, $f^{\epsilon}:= f\mathbb{1}_{\{f\geq \epsilon\}}$ and $f^{\epsilon}_k:= 2^kf^{\epsilon}$.

Also define $\alpha^{\epsilon}_k := 2^{-k}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\,\mu\{f^{\epsilon}\geq n2^{-k}\}$.

On p.98, in the proof of the 2nd statement (4.8) of Theo.4.26 (viz.  $\int_\Omega\,f\,d\mu = \int_0^\infty\,\mu\{f\geq t\}\,dt$), Klenke writes: $\alpha^{\epsilon}_k \rightarrow \int_0^\infty g^{\epsilon}(t)\,dt$ as $k\rightarrow \infty$.

He seems to be using an approximation to the integral in some way. How does this happen?

Answer (score 0):

For simple functions
$$g^k(t)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \mu(\{f^\varepsilon \geq n 2^{-k}\}) {\mathbf 1}_{[(n-1)2^{-k},n2^{-k})}$$
we have $g^k \uparrow g^\varepsilon$ and thus
$$\alpha_k^\varepsilon = \int_\varepsilon^\infty g^k(t)\,dt \rightarrow \int_\varepsilon^\infty g^\varepsilon \,dt$$
by Lemma 4.6(i) on page 87.